# Adding new value to model is not showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is `app.js`

```
angular.module('mobApp', ['ionic', 'mobApp.controllers', 'mobApp.services', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('listitems', {
      url: '/listitems',
      templateUrl: 'templates/listitems.html'
    })

  .state('publishmsg/form/new-message', {
      url: '/publishmsg/form/new-message',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormController'
  })  

  .state('publishmsg/form/add-tags', {
      url: '/publishmsg/form/add-tags',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form-tags.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormController'
  })    

  .state('publishmsg/form/add-location', {
      url: '/publishmsg/form/add-location',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form-location.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormController'
  });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/listitems');
});
```

Here is `publishMessageFormController` :

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers",['ionic','ngTagsInput','google.places'])
.controller("publishMessageFormController",function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $cordovaToast, $compile, deviceStatus, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicHistory){

$scope.finalPubFormModal = {};

$scope.geoSelectionDone = function()
{  

      $scope.finalPubFormModal.location = "fObj";
      console.log("Log1"+JSON.stringify($scope.finalPubFormModal));    
}

$scope.submitNewPublishMessage = function()
{  
  console.log("Log2"+JSON.stringify($scope.finalPubFormModal));
}
```

Here is `publishmsg-form-location.html`:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search Location">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-done" ng-disabled="npubmUsrLocForm.form.$invalid"  ng-click="geoSelectionDone()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content> 
    <form name="npubmUsrLocForm.form" class="css-form" novalidate>  
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input placeholder="Type location name" type="text"  ng-model="userCustmLocModel.location" ng-minlength="3" required/>
            </label>
         </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is `publishmsg-form.html` :

```
<ion-view view-title="Publish message">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">    
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-done" ng-disabled="npubmForm.msgForm.$invalid"  ng-click="submitNewPublishMessage()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

The problem is inside controller `log1` prints the new `location` value but `log2` doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the reason is that each of the pages has a separate instance of the controller. You could try sharing the data through a service. Something like

```
angular.module('mobApp.services').service('finalPub', function() {
    this.finalPubFormModal = {};    
    this.geoSelectionDone = function(value)
    {  
        this.finalPubFormModal.location = value;
    }
});
```

then you include that service in your controllers

```
.controller("publishMessageFormController",function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $cordovaToast, $compile, deviceStatus, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicHistory,finalPub){ ...
```

and then use the servie in the controllers

```
$scope.geoSelectionDone = function()
{  
      finalPub.geoSelectionDone("fObj");
}
```

Comment: but in app.js you can see all page i am refering to same controller

Comment: That is true, but as far as I recall, a new instance of the controller will be created for each of the routes - to give you a parallel in OOP, think of it like this: You have defined a class publishMessageFormController, then created var controller1 = new publishMessageFormController(), var controller2 = new publishMessageFormController() - if you set something in controller1, nothing will change in controller2.